# Woocommerce display widget on specific product category and its sub categories archive pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

The main parent category is 'encore-cases' and it has 15 sub-categories. I would like to display the product filter widget on main category 'encore-cases' and on all sub-category pages.

I tried using widget logic plugin with code (is_product_category('encore-cases')) and it display the widget on main category 'encore-cases' page but how do I show the same widget on sub-category pages?

Comment: There must be option for widget show/hide on product catalog and on single product. Or you can use common widget sidebar for woocommerce from Dashboard > Widgets >Wocommerce Sidebar.

Comment: Thank you @nir. The product filter plugin which has created widget has show/hide option for subcategories.

Comment: Welcome. Glad that comment helped you !!